# how can I add sub menu to the leaves top menu in odoo10?

Tags: menuitem, odoo-10

I want to add menu item to the Leave management top menu and I got error in my XML file that it want external ID.. how can I inherit this top menu to my module?

Comment: Post the code what you tried..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put your id and menu name here. If you inherit any module name than put their menu id in parent.

```
<menuitem id="main_menu_id" name="Main Menu Name"/> <!-- Top menu define -->
<menuitem id="sub_menu_id" name="Sub Menu Name" action="your_action" parent="main_menu_id"/> <!-- Child menu define -->
```